# How to stop the Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate

Tags: python, audio, pygame, fatal-error

When I insert sound and use it in Pygame, it quits, and it shows me this error:  Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate, I want to fix it....

I am using python 3.7.2 on Mac OS with Pycharme

-I tried deactivating the sound to be sure that it is the one causing the error, and it actually is, because when I deactivated, Pygame didn't quit nor showed me this error

-I tried changing the sound format from wav to ogg

-I tried putting the sound in the function not the events

-tried loading the image in the event

All of these didn't work, and tried random things, didn't know what to do...

## soundd

```
    self.bulletOO = pg.mixer.Sound("Bullet.ogg")
```

if self.aimR:

```
elf.bullet = Bullet(self.player.rect.x + 90 - self.bulletSpeed,
self.player.rect.y + self.y)   

self.bullet.image = pg.image.load("bulletP-R.png")

self.allSprites.add(self.bullet)

self.bulletGroupR.add(self.bullet)

self.bulletGroup.add(self.bullet)

self.bulletOO = pg.mixer.Sound("Bullet.ogg")

self.bulletOO.play()
```

I expect to hear sounds without that the game quits, but It quits, and weirdly, it quits randomly. I mean, some rare times it doesn't quit but If I continue shooting (using the sound) it quits suddenly, and sometimes it quits from the first time...

Answer (score 1):

The underlying cause of this is probably an SDL bug, but in my experience it is possible to work around it by explicitly setting the frequency of the mixer. By default, in pygame 1, the mixer frequency is set to 22050; in pygame 2 it is set to 44100. Setting it to 44100 in pygame 1 stopped this crash happening for me:

```py
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=44100)
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init(frequency=44100)
```

It's not clear if both of these init settings for the mixer are needed, but it doesn't hurt to add both, and for me it stopped the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('Bullet.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

And check the documentation here: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html